# Changing $\cos(x)$ to a form I have not seen before

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Simply put, I had to find the critical points, and classify them, with several functions including $z= \cos(\pi x) \cos(\pi y)$. Upon finding $Z(x), Z(y), Z(xx), Z(yy)$ and $Z(xy)$ I found $H$ to always be positive.

However I am unable to classify the critical points. I found $x=n(1)$ and $y=m(2)$ where $n(1)$ and $m(2)$ are any real integers. Upon looking at my lectures solutions, he stated the following although I am unsure why this is true:

$$Z(xx) = -(\pi)^2 \cos(\pi n(1)) \cos(\pi m(2)) \hspace{.1cm} \text{(I understand this)} $$
      $$= (\pi)^2 (-1)^x\text{ where }x= n(1)+m(2)+1     \hspace{.1cm} \text{(I don't understand where this came from)}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is found by noting that
$$\cos(\pi n)=(-1)^n$$
for integer $n$. In particular, the term $(-1)^n$ represents a certain alternation with $n$ - it is $1$ when $n$ is even and $-1$ when $n$ is odd. This happens to be exactly what $\cos(\pi n)$ does, so the expressions are equal. They've just done two steps using this:
$$\cos(\pi n)\cos(\pi m)=(-1)^n(-1)^m=(-1)^{n+m}.$$